# In Diamonsters, what happens to the cards on your monster board at the end of a round?

Tags: diamonsters

The rules are very unclear on this. Do we take these cards on hand for the next round? Are they discarded? Or shuffled into the draw pile?

And do I keep the current 5 cards in my hand, or do I start over with cards 1-5?

Comment: Could you please create a tag wiki for diamonsters so that the tag doesn't get removed in 6 months?

Answer (score 1):

Based on reading around at forums such as BoardGameGeeks, the usual approach is to reset the hands every time a diamond is won. That seems fairly settled.

As to your main question, I have been discarding all collected monster cards each round. It seems to me that as the deck slowly dwindles the game is likely to get more challenging, because everyone has increasing information about the deck. Resetting the hand is important because the uniform hand is a basic concept of the game, but I don't see the point in playing 3-5 rounds that are exactly identical. That is, if you reset the deck as well, each round is merely a replay with a different shuffle. The limit of 3-5 rounds then becomes an even more arbitrary cutoff than it already is.